# foundation 5 navigation bar title color change

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm trying to change the default color for my title, which is white at the moment.

```
<nav class = "top-bar" data-topbar>
    <ul class = "title-area">
        <li class = "name">
            <h1><%= link_to "CF logo", root_path, class: "home"%></h1>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried calling

```
.name h1{
    color:red;
}
```

and

```
.title-area .name h1{
    color:red;
}
```

even

```
.home{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-color: red;
}
```

but none of them works. What can I do?

Comment: I don't often code with the space in-between the equal symbol. Please remove the extra spaces before and after the `=` symbol. Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your title is inside of an anchor tag `<a>` - you'll want something like this:

```
.top-bar .name a { color: #9dcf81; }
```

Inside Chrome, after you inspect your element, look for the plus symbol once you highlight your title with a mouse click. Consider using the `!important` attribute if the color doesn't stick.

p.s. - Please provide a link with a URL Shortening service (if your concerned about privacy) to your site.

[image: Just right click and inspect element]

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not a CSS rule is used is dependent on the selectors specificity. See [the MDN for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) on how specificity for a CSS selector is calculated.

If you want to see which CSS statement is overriding your one (presumably one of the styles specified in the Foundation CSS library that you are using), then I would recommend a tool like firebug or chrome developer tools which allow you to inspect an element and see which rules are being taken into account and which are being overridden by more specific selectors.

You can also use [`important!`](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm) inside a selector to override the specificity, however use this with caution. So for example:-

```
.name h1 {
    color:red !important;
}
```

Comment: adding !important doesn't seem like it's solving the problem

Comment: if the `!important` doesn't work, I believe your targeting the wrong container, or it's overlapping with another `!important` that has priority.